# how to convert date to long in android

Tags: android, date, time

i want to convert 2014-06-24 10:02:04 formatted date into milliseconds
any support will be appreciable 
thank you

```
  public static long parseDate(String text)
        throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a MM/dd/yyyy",
                                                           Locale.US);      
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return dateFormat.parse(text).getTime();
    }
```

Comment: okay question may be duplicated but i cant get proper answer what I'm looking in stack overflow thats why i posted my question here.but i found what i miss my code. so i solved my problem.thanks for your feed back

Comment: but above mentioned answer is not a satisfactory answer for my qiestion